# Return object of certain class from vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, vector

I need a function to find components of a class type from an array of components in another class.

This function doesn't work and gives "type name is not allowed" when used...

```
template<typename T> auto* GetComponent(T& comp)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Components.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (static_cast<T*>(Components.at(i))) return Components.at(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: (1) Error messages contain more text than that. Don't paraphrase it, copy the entire text directly. (2) Even if that error is fixed, this function isn't going to do what you want in the long run, because `static_cast` doesn't do run time type checks (I assume you want to *check* the object is of the correct type).

Comment: So how would you get an object of a specified derived class from a vector of the base class?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` seems more appropriate than `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using `dynamic_cast` rather than `static_cast`, as suggested by Jarod42.  Two templates, `For` to perform a functor on each matching type, and `GetComponent` which is closer to the provided code snippet in the question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace {

struct Animal { virtual ~Animal(); };

Animal::~Animal() = default;

struct Horse : Animal { };

struct Dog : Animal { };

struct Zebra : Animal { };

struct Cow : Animal {
    std::string noise;
    Cow(std::string noise_) : noise{std::move(noise_)} { }
    void print(std::ostream&) const;
};

void Cow::print(std::ostream& out) const {
    out << "Cow says " << noise << "\n";
}

template <typename T, typename C, typename F>
void For(C const& container, F fn) {
    for (auto const& item : container) {
        auto p = dynamic_cast<T const*>(item);
        if (p != nullptr) fn(*p);
    }
}

template<typename T, typename C> auto* GetComponent(C const& container) {
    for (auto const& item : container) {
        auto p = dynamic_cast<T const*>(item);
        if (p != nullptr) return p;
    }

    return static_cast<T const*>(nullptr);
}


} // anon

int main() {
    Horse horse;
    Cow cow1{"moo"};
    Dog dog;
    Cow cow2{"snort"};

    std::vector<Animal*> v;
    v.push_back(&horse);
    v.push_back(&cow1);
    v.push_back(&dog);
    v.push_back(&cow2);

    For<Cow>(v, [](Cow const& cow) { cow.print(std::cout); });

    auto first_cow = GetComponent<Cow>(v);
    std::cout << "first cow:";

    if (first_cow) first_cow->print(std::cout);
    else std::cout << "(null)\n";

    auto first_dog = GetComponent<Dog>(v);
    std::cout << "first dog:" << (first_dog ? "yes" : "(null)") << "\n";

    auto first_zebra = GetComponent<Zebra>(v);
    std::cout << "first zebra:" << (first_zebra ? "yes" : "(null)") << "\n";
}
```